# Should all the libuv API be called in loop thread?

Tags: c++, libuv

Libuv api is not thread safe but uv_async_send.

like the following codes, the 'uv_idle_stop' should not be called in the other thread ?

```
auto loop = uv_default_loop();
    uv_idle_t idle;
    uv_idle_init(loop, &idle);
    uv_idle_start(&idle, _DoIdleWork);
    std::thread th([&]() {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
        // this should use uv_async_send ?
        uv_idle_stop(&idle); 
    });
    uv_run(loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);
    th.join();
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: is that right ? Call uv_idle_stop in another thread ?